# How to trigger an event when I click and scroll the scrollbar of the div container in JQuery~?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

E.g:

```
.container{width:300px; height:300px; overflow:scroll;}

<div class="container">
 with long contents which make the container scroll....
</div>
```

And I want to `trigger` `events` when I `click and scroll` the `scrollbar` of `container`.

Because I have `events binded` to container.So,I don't want the `scrollbar's event` is binded to the `container` itselft.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind multiple events via jQuery like this:

```
$('.container').bind('click scroll', function() {      
    alert('scroll or click occurred')
});
```